# why doesn't apex supports select * from Objectname

Tags: apex, soql, query

Why doesn't apex supports

```
SELECT * FROM OBJECTNAME;
```

but allows to query all fields through dynamic query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This statement is false in some scenarios that you can query all fields. SOQL also comes under governor limit.

- You cannot write a query which extend 20000 characters

So you may not query all fields if Api name of field is 80 character long and you have referenced 500 fields, it will have 40000 characters which will throw exception. Also, query 500 fields is not a very realistic scenario but having 500 fields can be possible easily so using `SELECT *` will give you freedom to query all fields which will cost to system performance. It won't be a optimized use of multi-tenant architecture system.

It is an architecture level decision that no extra field should be referenced in query so system resource can be used optimized. Each extra field count against heap size as well.